# Difficulty executing a shell script from a python script

Tags: python, shell, scripting, subprocess

When I run a shell script in terminal it works as I want it to
In terminal when I type: ./hello.sh
pdflatex runs and the file compiles.  It works perfectly.  pdflatex creates a pdf file and it's all good.

I have a python script in the same directory as the shell script.  When I run that script with a call to the shell script nothing happens

The code does not error out

I've looked through the forums, but this specific question is not addressed

The shell script called hello.sh contains:

```
#! /bin/bash
pdflatex n1.tex
```

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', './hello.sh'],shell=True)
```

All I want to happen is that when I run this python script it executes the shell script and the other program pdflatex creates the pdf document

Comment: if you use `shell=True` then you use string `'/bin/bash ./hello.sh'` instead of list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['/bin/bash', './hello.sh'])
```

Or alternatively

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['./hello.sh'])
```

Or even

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['pdflatex', 'n1.tex'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I used your third option, but had to add the full path to pdflatex for it to work.  I'm not sure why it needed to be added bc when I just type it into terminal it works automatically.

Comment: @Jim I'm glad it worked for you. Can you please mark the answer as valid and upvote the answer if you think it was useful?

Comment: Hawkings, I did upvote the answer and mark it.  I think that since I'm new to this the upvote is registered, but does not show up.  But thanks